# Upload warning when aab file generated by cn1 to Google play

Tags: codenameone

I upload aab file generated by cn1 to google play but got the following warning.

```
Your app currently targets API level 30 and must target at least API level 31 to ensure 
it is built on the latest APIs optimized for security and performance.
```

Any suggestion to solve this warning?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is a standard process from Google. It's being tracked in this [reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/cn1/comments/wk4uu1/google_play_starts_asking_for_sdk_31/). We're working on fixing the build issues for those newer targets.